# Lightning Community, can i make change password Lightning Page, not VF?

Tags: lightning-experience, customer-community, napili

We have Lightning Community, with only lightning components (no Visualforce).

But when we try to modify default `ChangePassword` page (one were you enter your new password and password confirmation), we have only two options: `Default` and `VisualForce Page`. Why? Why are there no options to use Lightning Page here? Did I miss some steps in configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lightning framework is evolving and Salesforce adds new features in each release.

I see that documentation suggest that you might use [Lightning Community Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_intro.htm) to use [Lightning Components to modify ChangePassword page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_password_management.htm&type=0).

Also it is suggested [here](https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_lightning_in_communities.htm&type=5) that

> The Community Builder is like the Lightning App Builder, except that
>   it’s used to design and build communities using Lightning components.
>   Just like the Lightning App Builder, you can use standard or custom
>   components so administrators can create community pages with
>   point-and-click customization.

============================================================

Ok, I now see your point, despite it is declared in the documentation that this is possible to use Lightning Community Builder for all login pages (Login, ChangePassword, ForgotPassword), it is actually available only for Login and ForgotPassword but not for ChangePassword.

So even if you create a Lightning Community Builder page called ChangePassword it won't appear as an option for ChangePassword override:
[image]

I believe this is a drawback in design of Lightning Community Builder and it is possible to create an idea for Salesforce to implement this in the new release (for example, in Spring 2018).

Since there are no similar ideas on Ideas Exchange, [I created a one there](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lHZjQAM). If you persuade 250 users to vote for that idea then it might get considered to be included and implemented in the Spring 2018 release.

For now in the current Winter 2018 release you can try to use Visualforce with Lightning Theme. As Doug suggested, it is possible to use [Lightning Out feature, which allows to have Lightning Components inside of Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

Another option is to use just Lightning Theme without Lightning Component but with native HTML and Javascript, you can refer to [Lightning Design System.](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/)

For that to work you need to add tag `<apex:slds />` to your page and wrap your code in a container:
`<div class="slds-scope">...</div>`

Comment: The OP referenced the feature you linked to in the question, which shows how to override the Change Password page in **Visualforce**, not Lightning.  I don't think the title you provided for that link really matches the content.

Comment: @DougFriedman The documentation is misleading: it is suggesting that user can configure Lightning Community Page for both ForgotPassword and ChangePassword pages, but in fact, you can override ForgotPassword with custom Lightning Community Page, but you can't override ChangePassword  with custom Lightning Community Page

Answer (score 3):

While it is still the case that you cannot directly override the Change Password page with a Lightning Component, you can always embed a Lightning Component within a Visualforce Page. You can call the following Apex from any context to change the user's password:

```
Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldpassword);
```

Follow these instructions and you're good to go:

[Embed Lightning Component in a VF Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

[Site Class in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm)

Comment: Thanks Doug, that is one way to do it. But i'm looking for "NO VF" solution here.  We are using Lightning Theme and that's a main reason i don't want to use Visualforce.

Comment: Hey Doug, I'm finding that lightning out is not working on this page... have you had any experience otherwise? I think this is due to the special nature of this page (a custom html page that wraps the vf page that you provide for login).

Comment: Doug or @CasparHarmer, were either of you successful using Lightning component through a vf page to do this? I have not been able to.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for solution for that one - situation up to 30.04.2022 still the same - we are NOT allowed to override the page with Community Builder page (as suggested by documentation), and using Lightning Out to expose Lightning component there inside VF - also NOT possible. So... Only VF for now.

[Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeSIUAZ/allow-to-override-changepassword-by-lightning-community-builder-page) also still on the same place