# How can I use the Change Password component in Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community

Following up this question [Lightning Community, can i make change password Lightning Page, not VF?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197137/lightning-community-can-i-make-change-password-lightning-page-not-vf), I am wondering if it is possible to make use of the Change Password lightning component:

[image]

It is not documented anywhere, and it is not used in standard pages.

[image]

[image]

The default Reset Password page uses some standard salesforce-like change password form.
[image]

The Visualforce page, well it's pretty basic VF page...

So here are my questions:

1. Where can I use the Change Password component?
2. Is is possible to customize this component?

Comment: It looks like it's only usable under when looking at page under "Login" area. Or at least it only shows as an available component for certain pages...

Answer (score 4):

I have posted a similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269341/how-to-customise-change-password-in-communities-and-keep-community-branding) several months ago, did not get any answer.

But this is the response received from Salesforce support back in Aug 2019:

> only reset and forgot password pages can be customized. There is no option to customize the change password page - Case # 23746419

Not sure if anything has changed since that response and there is also an open idea on this topic [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lHZjQAM)